# Azure Kinect DK - releasing capture/cluster containing timestamp has already been written to disk

Tags: windows, azure, kinect, recording

trying to record a relatively lengthy video (7-8 hours) using k4arecorder.exe. Have tried to split it up into hourlong recordings, or record it in one go. It will occasionally record fine, but will randomly crash with the following error messages included in the screenshot. Sometimes this occurs at 15 minutes, sometimes after 5 hours, sometimes not at all. Can anyone explain this error to me?

errors are:

releasing capture early due to full queue T5

The cluster containing the timestamp -XXXX has already been written to disk.

Returned failure in k4a recurd write capture ()
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V65Pz.jpg)